# Matrix norm boundedness in one norm means boundedness in the other

Tags: linear-algebra

How can we show that:

$||x||_\infty \leq ||x||_2 \leq \sqrt{n} ||x||_\infty$

$||A||_\infty \leq \sqrt{n}||A||_2 \leq n||A||_\infty$

Where A is $n\times n$ and $x$ is $n$ vector.

I think this implies the equivalence of these norms for finite $n$, that is boundedness in one norm also means boundedness in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{\|A\|_{\infty}}{\|A\|_2}
=\frac{\max\limits_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_{\infty}}{\|x\|_{\infty}}}{\max\limits_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}}
\leq \max\limits_{x\neq 0}\frac{\frac{\|Ax\|_{\infty}}{\|x\|_{\infty}}}{\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}}
=\max\limits_{x\neq 0} \left(\frac{\|Ax\|_{\infty}}{\|Ax\|_2}\cdot \frac{\|x\|_2}{\|x\|_{\infty}}\right)
\\
\leq\max\limits_{x\neq 0} \frac{\|Ax\|_{\infty}}{\|Ax\|_2}\cdot \max\limits_{x\neq 0} \frac{\|x\|_2}{\|x\|_{\infty}}
=1\cdot \sqrt{n} = \sqrt{n}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\|A\|_2}{\|A\|_{\infty}}
=\frac{\max\limits_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}}{\max\limits_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_{\infty}}{\|x\|_{\infty}}}
\leq \max\limits_{x\neq 0}\frac{\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}}{\frac{\|Ax\|_{\infty}}{\|x\|_{\infty}}}
=\max\limits_{x\neq 0} \left(\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|Ax\|_{\infty}}\cdot \frac{\|x\|_{\infty}}{\|x\|_2}\right)
\\
\leq\max\limits_{x\neq 0} \frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|Ax\|_{\infty}}\cdot \max\limits_{x\neq 0} \frac{\|x\|_{\infty}}{\|x\|_2}
=\sqrt{n}\cdot 1 = \sqrt{n}
$$